# Flash scaling not working in IE9

Tags: flash

I am trying to create a web page that will make a flash movie either the movies height, or if the window is to small, will scall it down so that it will fit inside window but maintain it's aspect ratio.

I have it working in every browser except IE9. IE9 seems to ignore the showall scale setting and instead stretches the video.

Comment: Here is my sample code: File -> Publish. Ass.

Comment: I'm having the same problem using scale => noscale